# Phpmyadmin/MySQL Create Foreign Key Error

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys

I am trying to create a foreign key constraints between tables with phpmyadmin, all tables involved are InnoDB. The related tables are:

- User
- Level
- UserLevel

UserLevel is indexed with user_id and level_id columns, which I would like the foreign key constraints on. The constraint goes on the level_id column without issue, but user_id fails with this error: "Error creating foreign key on user_id (check data types)"

Both columns are of type int(11) NOT NULL and signed. I have another table that is successfully linked to User through a foreign key, but I cannot see any differences between these columns.

Does anyone see what I'm missing here?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711232/mysql-error-creating-foreign-key-on-columname-check-data-types and specifically @ademup 's answer : that error will also occur if you already have a foreign key of the same name

Comment: That was indeed the answer I was looking for. I didn't realize that constraint existed, thanks!